# Flurry Ads causing linker errors

Tags: swift, flurry, xcode6.3, ios8.3

I have imported `libFlurryAds_6.4.0.a` in my project along with `FlurryAdInterstial.h` and `FlurryAdInterstitialDelegate.h`.

Then I added `Security.framework` and `SystemConfiguration.framework` under **Build Phases** > **Link with Binary Librarires**

Then I added this bridging header, and added it under **Project Build Settings** > **Swift Compiler - Code Generation** > **Objective-C Bridging Header** > **debug** and **release** values:

```
#ifndef Foo_Bridging_Header_h
#define Foo_Bridging_Header_h
#import "FlurryAdInterstitial.h"
#import "FlurryAdInterstitialDelegate.h"
#endif
```

Then in my view controller `viewDidLoad()`, I added this code:

```
    adInterstitial = FlurryAdInterstitial(space: "Foo Interstitial") //adInterstitial is a class variable
```

When I compile, I get the following errors:

[image]

if I remove the variable, the compile is successful. I don't understand the error and hence am not sure what I can do to resolve of this! Help!

Answer (score 1):

The FlurryAds SDK requires some additional frameworks in addition to the frameworks that the Flurry Analytics SDK requires.

In your case, it sounds like you are missing AdSupport.framework.

For a full list of required frameworks, check the following site: https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/publisher/code/ios/

Comment: Uggh, such a silly mistake! Don't know how I missed it. Thanks!